# How to return boolean from async await function instead of Promise<boolean> (Typescript | React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, async-await

So i'm working in React.js and i have a Calendar Component from AntDesign that includes a disabledDate prop.

This disabledDate prop recieves a boolean as response and it checks every date from the Calendar Component.

The thing is that my client gave me an API that sends me a 200 response if it finds some data (it means that the Date is available for scheduling) and a 404 response if it don't

So what i'm doing is that i created a function that checks if a given date is available or not and based on the result from this function, the disabledDate prop will enable or disable a Date from the Calendar component.

The problem now is that disabledDate can't recieve a Promise, it needs a Boolean, and when i turn it into async it obviously would return a Promise instead of a Boolean.

Is there any workaround or i'm missing completely the point

This is my function

```js
export const isDateAvailable = async (
  specialistID: number | undefined,
  serviceID: number | undefined,
  date: moment.Moment
) => {
  const body = {
    especialista_id: specialistID,
    servicio_id: serviceID,
    fecha: date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
  };

  const response = await axios.get(API_URL + "/disponibilidadAtencion", {
    params: body,
  });

  if (response.status === 404) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};
```

This is my Calendar Component

```html
<Calendar
    fullscreen={false}
    mode={"month"}
    disabledDate={async (current) => {
      if (current.fromNow() === "a few seconds ago") return false;
      const dateAvailability = await isDateAvailable(
        selectedSpecialist?.especialista_id,
        selectedService?.servicio_id,
        current
      );
      console.log(dateAvailability);
      return current < moment() || !dateAvailability;
    }}
  />
```

Comment: you will always get true, you need to use async await or thenables..

Comment: Yeah, that is what i'm trying to solve, cuz i can't turn disabledDate to async

Comment: The function, as written, will always return true, it already is returning a boolean. Are you wanting/trying to return the value of the fetch request?

Comment: Yes, i edited now.

As i said, i want to return true or false based on fetch status.

But i can't make disabledDate async cuz it needs a boolean to be passed

Comment: Should be setting state instead since `isDateAvailable()` is async. Pass your state params to the `<Calendar>`

Comment: Either way, with the fetch, you'll need wait for the axios promise to resolve. What is the driving force on needing to call `isDateAvailable`? Is it in response to some interaction/event? You should save the result in state and render the calendar when the data is ready and available.

Comment: How i could set it into an state? cuz its not only one date. The disabledDate checks every date from the calendar. If it returns true, the current date is disabled if not its enabled

Comment: Your frontend has *three* states, available, unavailable and unknown. Your frontend should be able to reflect that (just having enabled / disabled dates does not work)

Comment: I would really apreacciate a detailed comment on this one. I think i'm lost :(

Comment: In reponse to Drew Reese, i need to check if the Dates are available cuz its like a Booking Web. So the Calendar should disable the dates that are not available.

Comment: So, presumably you have a function that is called to make a booking.... and as Jonas points out, your app would be in the "unknown" or "pending" state while a booking request is checked, and once the `isDateAvailable` value resolves you can leave the "pending " state and either return to the "unbookable" state or update to the "bookable" state. Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

The ideal way would be use state variable to hold `isDateAvailabe()` response and use the state variable inside the `Calendar` component.

The other thing you need to decide, how should be  component behave while you function isDateAvailable() is resolving. It can either be hidden or in disabled state, depending on your use case.

Below code sample you can use for your reference, its disable the calender component while api call is fetched.

```js
export default CalendarWrapper = () => {
  const [isDisabled, setDisabled] = useState(false)
  
  useEffect(() => {
   isDateAvailable(
        selectedSpecialist?.especialista_id,
        selectedService?.servicio_id,
        current
    ).then (dateAvailability => {
      setDisabled(current < moment() || !dateAvailability)
    });
  }, [])

  return (
  <>
    <Calendar
    fullscreen={false}
    mode={"month"}
    disabledDate={isDisabled}
    />
  </>
)
}
```